# How do I get a Row count from a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview I'd like to customize based on how many rows it has.

If it has no rows, I'd like the background image to prompt the user to add content.
If it has 1 or more rows, I'd like it to have a different background image, in order to display the content.

I'm using a fetched results controller to populate my tableview, by the way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well this is generally very easy to accomplish as you need only to have UITableView properly delegated to your ViewController with appropriate delegate methods included in your .m file.

Then you can anywhere get row count like this:

```
[tablePropertyName numberOfRowsInSection:SECTION_NUMBER];
```

where section number is 0 for first section, 1 for second, etc.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it is the better solution. Rather than relying on your data source count, you can just use that property to determine the number of rows in that section. That way regardless of what happens to your data source (might get corrupted) you are adding the row at the right place.

Answer (score 10):

In Swift, you can get the UITableView rows count by

```
yourTableViewName.numberOfRows(inSection: Int)
```

example:

```
yourTableViewName.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) // returns rows count in section 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Sixten Otto's answer.

```
[myFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
```

However there's more. Above line would return the number of objects regardless the sections. However if you would want to perform this on a table with multiple sections, you would have to call it the following way.

```
[[myFetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:<section>] numberOfObjects];
```

You can get the objects for the section like this.

```
[[myFetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:<section>] objects];
```

** You have to replace  with the number representing the section.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at the documentation for [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It has example code for implementing the methods of `UITableViewDataSource` (including the ones that say how many sections the table has, and how many rows in each section), as well as documenting the property [fetchedObjects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/fetchedObjects), which you could use to see how many raw results you fetched.

```
[myFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
```

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.numberOfRows(inSection:)` returns numbers of row in section, this method may not trigger fetched results controller's core data query.

```swift
let numberOfItems = (0..<tableView.numberOfSections).reduce(into: 0) { partialResult, sectionIndex in
    partialResult += tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex)
}
```